# How to align list elements horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to create a horizontal list of tags. I consulted [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_horizontal), but their method is not working. My `li` elements are stacking on top of each other and are not in the `ul` div that is shown in orange. How do I make a horizontal list of tags?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class = "row">
        <div class = "cell">
            <div class = "album_container" >
                <a href = "">
                    <div class = "album_bar_wrapper">
                        <div class = "album_bar">
                            <div class = "float_left left_button"><a class = "buttons "><img class = "album_icon" src = "images/trash.png" alt = "trash" width = "30"/></a></div>
                            <div class = "float_right right_button"><a class = "buttons "> Edit </a></div>
                        </div>
                        <img class = "album_image" src = "images/defaultAlbum.png" alt = "default album" width = "300"/>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <ul class = "tags_list">
                    <li class = "tags">summer</li>
                    <li class = "tags">college</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tags_list {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.tags_list li {
    display: inline;
}

.tags {
    position: absolute; /*tags are positioned relative to album container*/
}
```

Comment: Remove `.tags { position: absolute; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tags_list > .tags 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

(and erase that absolute position rule)

Answer (score 1):

That's how to display horizontally every li of an ul ^^

```css
    ul {
        display: table;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
        <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
```